# Decode email messages to UTF-7 with PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, imap

I have been trying convert many IMAP message bodies to something more readable (UTF-8 or equivalent). I cannot seem to find an out-of-the box function to work.

Here is an example of what I am trying to decode:

```
President Trump signed an executive order Thursday tar= geting North Korea=E2=80=99s trading partners, calling it a =E2=80=9Cpowerful=E2= =80=9D new tool aimed at isolating and de-nuclearizing the regime.


More on thi= s: http://www.foxnews.com= /politics/2017/09/21/trump-signs-executive-order-targeting-north-koreas-tra= ding-partners.html
```

(in the sample above, any "= ", there should be a newline)

**A few things that I have tried:**

```
iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $data); 
//this resulted in a server error 500

imap_mime_header_decode($data); 
//this outputs an array (just something that I tried; yes, I know that it is only good for headers)

iconv_mime_decode($test, 0, "ISO-8859-1");
//This works for a few messages (plaintext ones) but does not output anything for the example above; for others, it only outputs part of the message body

mb_convert_encoding($test, "UTF8");
//this results in another internal server error!

$data = str_replace("=92", "'", $data);
//I have also tried to manually find and replace an occurrence of a utf-7 (I guess) encoded string
```

Anyways, there is something that I am doing totally wrong but not sure what. How do you all read the body of an email retrieved with IMAP?

What are some other things that I can try? People must do just this the entire time but I can't seem to find a solution...

Thank you,
Rog

Comment: You mean UTF-8, not UTF-7? You write UTF-7 in the question, but the code uses UTF-8.

Comment: This is called Quoted-Printable encoding.  It is not a character set, it is an encoding of some other character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually dealing with the UTF-7 encoding here.  What you're actually seeing is [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

[php contains a function to decode this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php)

I actually haven't written php in quite some time so forgive my style failures, here's an example which decodes your text:

```
<?php
$s = 'President Trump signed an executive order Thursday tar= geting North Korea=E2=80=99s trading partners, calling it a =E2=80=9Cpowerful=E2= =80=9D new tool aimed at isolating and de-nuclearizing the regime.';

// It's unclear why I have to replace out `= `, I have a feeling these
// are actually newlines and copy paste error?
echo quoted_printable_decode(str_replace('= ', '', $s));
?>
```

When run it produces:

```
President Trump signed an executive order Thursday targeting North Korea’s trading partners, calling it a “powerful” new tool aimed at isolating and de-nuclearizing the regime.
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working great now! Selected answer. Again, thank you all for the help.